# Last result of heavy processing of stream of events

Tags: multithreading, scala

There is a stream of events being processed by a costly algorithm which executes for a very long time. Results for all events except last (at every moment) are of no interest. I want to process an event asynchronously interrupting processing of previous events each time a new one arrives.

Are there any good patterns or techniques to do so?

I've considered:

- actors (no cancellation)
- futures (no cancellation)
- threads (not clear how should last event be selected, and they are usually heavy)
- thread pools (require custom solution, not Scala way?)

I tend to choose pools, with a custom interruptible tasklet (not yet designed). Are there better options in Scala? If not how should I implement my tasklet?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can suggest is using Java futures and calling `cancel` on the Java future. You will then need to handle `InterruptedException` (for blocking operations) and regularly check for `Thread.isInterrupted` (for compute-intensive operations). I guess you know about this already.